# Javascript handling JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This seems really bizarre...

I have some JSON...

```
{"firstName":"David","lastName":"Smith","email":null,"id":0}
```

But when I try to parse it and use it with...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var json = $.getJSON('userManagement/getUser');
        $("p").text(json.firstName);
    });
</script>

This is the user management view

Users : <p></p>
```

Nothing appears, but if I just do $("p").text(json); it tells me it's an object and I can see the JSON is correct in firebug, any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to use the value before it is returned from the response. See @iambriansreed's answer below.

Comment: @Alnitak The two downvotes you see were received on my own question. Sorry your question was downvoted mine was too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('userManagement/getUser',function(json){
            $("p").text(json.firstName);
        });            
    });
</script>
```

You have to work with the `json` variable after the AJAX request has completed.

Learn more here about AJAX JSON Requests: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Learn more here about general AJAX Requests: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thank you, I will accept this answer as it worked when the timer lets me :)

Comment: this answer is correct, but insufficient, as it doesn't explain _why_ your code is wrong.

Comment: @Alnitak I completely agree. It is of no real help, since Copy&Paste is always a bad teacher.

Comment: @Alnitak Code without explanation seems to have become the norm, and tends to attract the most upvotes because it's much easier/faster to post that kind of answer.

Comment: @Alnitak I thought "You have to work with the json variable after the AJAX request has completed." was pretty clear.

Comment: @iambriansreed I'm pretty sure you added that later

Comment: and no reason to downvote other correct answers, as I'm pretty sure you did this.

Comment: @Christoph yes, he has two downvotes recorded against this question.  Very bad form!

Comment: @Alnitak The two downvotes you see were received on my own question. Sorry your question was downvoted mine was too.

Comment: @iambriansreed yes, you're right - I misread the rep page - apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.getJSON()` function is just a wrapper around an AJAX call; it doesn't return the JSON that it gets as a result of the AJAX call, but instead returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object (thanks to Mathletics for clarifying this).

You'll need to supply a callback function to do whatever processing of the JSON you need.

Comment: It does not return a jQuery deferred, but rather a jqXHR: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR

Comment: @Mathletics although the `jqXHR` object implements the `promise` interface, so it's much the same thing.

Comment: @Mathletics I went to check the docs after posting my answer because I wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for letting me know, though - updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous - it doesn't return the JSON.

You need to supply a *callback function*, either using:

```
$.getJSON(url, callback);
```

or

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url);
jqxhr.done(success_callback); // will be passed the JSON
jqxhr.fail(error_callback);   // will be called if there's an error
```

the latter is more flexible, as you can also register error callbacks, which the raw `$.getJSON` method doesn't support.

Comment: Regarding to your question, take a look on two similar threads where @iambriansreed participated: [First](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10572350/601179), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10213620/601179). Should I continue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback-function, since you retrieve your data asynchronously.

The moment you call `$("p").text(json.firstName);` the JSON is not loaded yet.

Thats why you have to use:

`$.getJSON('userManagement/getUser',function(json){...your code here... }<-callback`